# SSRS Recursive Parent gives distinct children only, when children have multiple parents

Tags: sql, recursion, reporting-services, parent-child, distinct

I have made an SSRS report using the recursive parent functionality to show a hierarchical tree of values. The problem I have is that some children have more than one parent, but because (in order to use the recursive parent nicely) I need to group the results by Id, I only see distinct entries. This means that I only see each child once, even if it "should" appear in multiple locations in the report (under each of its parents).

Here is an example dataset that shows what I mean:

```
DECLARE @Bear Table
( ParentId  INT NOT NULL
 ,Id        INT NOT NULL
 ,Name      VARCHAR(255))

INSERT INTO @Bear
SELECT * FROM 
(SELECT 0 AS ParentId,  1 AS Id,    'Daddy Bear' AS Name    UNION
 SELECT 0 AS ParentId,  2 AS Id,    'Mummy Bear' AS Name    UNION
 SELECT 1 AS ParentId,  3 AS Id,    'Baby Bear'  AS Name    UNION
 SELECT 2 AS ParentId,  3 AS Id,    'Baby Bear'  AS Name)           AS FamilyMember
ORDER BY FamilyMember.Id

SELECT * FROM @Bear
```

My Actual data contains lots of "Baby Bears" where for instance a function is used by more than one procedure, or a procedure is used by more than one report.

When I make the report, I group on Bear.Id, with a recursive parent of Bear.ParentId, which gives me something like this (in the report table):

```
Level 1     Level 2
Daddy Bear
            Baby Bear
Mummy Bear
```

As you can see, "Baby Bear" only appears once (normally, Id would be unique and this would make perfect sense). What I would like is for SSRS to display is something more like this:

```
Level 1     Level 2
Daddy Bear
            Baby Bear
Mummy Bear
            Baby Bear
```

This would give the users a much better idea of the actual structure they are looking at.

So far, I have tried changing the report group to group by "cstr(Fields!Id.Value) & cstr(Fields!ParentId.Value)", in order to re-establish a unique grouping, so that no records are aggregated into invisibility, but this loses the ordering where children appear immediately after their parent, so I get something like this:

```
Level 1     Level 2
Daddy Bear
            Baby Bear
            Baby Bear
Mummy Bear
```

I have also tried adding ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Id, ParentId) as a new column in the query, to group on that, unquely, but SSRS seems to have a problem with this. The final workaround I am now using is to list only the distinct values as in the first example, but use an Action in each table row to run the report again for each node, on click. This is far from ideal, however.

I have also Googled without result.

I am stuck as to what to do.

Any help would be greatly appreciated - what should I do?

Thanks for your time,

Mark

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I'm facing the exact same problem right now. The answer below with row number is not working ofc, because you lose the parent child relation between id and parent id, if you replace the id grouping with a row number...

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you add the ROW_NUMBER() exactly?

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() over (order by parentid) as rn, * FROM 
(SELECT 0 AS ParentId,  1 AS Id,    'Daddy Bear' AS Name    UNION
 SELECT 0 AS ParentId,  2 AS Id,    'Mummy Bear' AS Name    UNION
 SELECT 1 AS ParentId,  3 AS Id,    'Baby Bear'  AS Name    UNION
 SELECT 2 AS ParentId,  3 AS Id,    'Baby Bear'  AS Name)           AS FamilyMember
```

Produces a "unique" id per row for grouping on.

**UPDATE**

So based on my understanding of your problem, you want a [recursive CTE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243.aspx). There are quite a few questions here on SO about them, so between that and that link I encourage you to figure out how to produce a dataset that fits your needs.

Comment: At the time of asking the question, the answer was "because I'm a fool and had an INT column as a VARCHAR" but, having sorted that out, the answer is that the sorting is lost (as per the third example in the question).

Comment: Sorry, it does indeed work using the example I gave - I will check why not with my actual data; there must be something else in there stopping it. I will post my discoveries.

Comment: If you have unique rows, you don't need to create an artificially unique grouping in your report grouping group by statement. Just group by rn, with a recursive parent of ParentID.

Comment: Each parent can only have one row number, so if a new level is added with Baby bear (renamed "Young bear" in the interests of realism) as the parent, then this level will only appear below one of the times that its parent is listed - the same record appears twice in the report, but since the row number is being grouped upon, it must be unique, causing the same distinct problems as example 1, but at the level below.

Comment: So yeah, you are trying to achieve duplication of unduplicated rows. IE if Baby Bear has a child element, and you want to see it under both instances of Baby Bear, you have to have two rows of it in your data set. SSRS is only ever going to put a row in one grouping.

Comment: Hi Kyle, the dataset was made using recursive CTEs; it is SSRS that is not displaying all the rows in the query (baby bear appears twice in the dataset). I can as we have discussed, use row_number() to group on a distinct list to display all the records in the query, but this loses the sorting. I suppose that the real question then is "is it possible to disassociate the sorting and the grouping while maintaining a good looking hierarchical list?". Apologies that I have been so unclear in my attempts to explain the problem.